# How to show ONLY the max value of a inner join table column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I used INNER JOIN on two tables :

```
Transactions 
 - transaction_id (PK)
 -ticket_id (FK) reference to ticketsforsale

Ticketsforsale : 
 - ticket_id (PK)
 - type
 - price
```

(there are more columns in each table but serve no purpose for this question)

The query i tried is the following :

```
SELECT ticketsforsale.type , SUM(ticketsforsale.price) AS TotalProfit
   FROM ticketsforsale INNER JOIN transactions 
   ON ticketsforsale.ticket_id = transactions.ticket_id 
GROUP BY ticketsforsale.type 

The result is : 
  Sports | 300
  Cruise | 600
  Theater| 100
```

I tried using this line in the query

```
WHERE TotalProfit = SELECT(MAX(TotalProfit)
```

But I can't figure out the right place for this line.

What i want the query to do is to show only the ROW containing the max value of "TotalProfit" . I am just missing the right MAX function usage on this query , thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and a limit the result set to one row:

```
SELECT tfs.type , SUM(tfs.price) AS TotalProfit
FROM ticketsforsale tfs INNER JOIN
     transactions t 
     ON tfs.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 
GROUP BY tfs.type 
ORDER BY TotalProfit DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases as well, so the query is easier to write and to read.

Based on this query, you don't seem to need the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tfs.type , SUM(tfs.price) AS TotalProfit
FROM ticketsforsale tfs 
GROUP BY tfs.type 
ORDER BY TotalProfit DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks man , i think i got too fixed on the MAX function that i couldn't figure out the simplest solution :P . The thing about the INNER JOIN is that i couldn't know what tickets where sold if i don't join the 2 tables because the "Sold Tickets" are listed in the "transaction" table . Anyway , thanks for your time and help once more :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CTE` and pick only one row based on `TotalProfit` values.

```
with cte as (
SELECT ticketsforsale.type , SUM(ticketsforsale.price) AS TotalProfit
   FROM ticketsforsale INNER JOIN transactions 
   ON ticketsforsale.ticket_id = transactions.ticket_id 
GROUP BY ticketsforsale.type 
)
select *
from cte 
order by TotalProfit desc
limit 1
```

If you want to use `max()`, you can do something like this:

```
with cte as (
SELECT ticketsforsale.type , SUM(ticketsforsale.price) AS TotalProfit
   FROM ticketsforsale INNER JOIN transactions 
   ON ticketsforsale.ticket_id = transactions.ticket_id 
GROUP BY ticketsforsale.type 
)
select *
from cte 
where TotalProfit = (select max(TotalProfit) from cte)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton , that worked like a charm. If you don't mind could you give me a solution using the "MAX()" function ? ( Just from sheer curiousity ) . :)

Comment: I added a solution with max() to the post.